# I'm trying to find out how to get fixed viewport regardless the device

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The example to give you all is [www.deliveryhobe.com](http://www.deliveryhobe.com). I'm trying to get the fixed viewport like they achieved there. My codebase is react and I'm using styled components.

Comment: Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />` to head

Comment: I checked the code of this website, and they achieved it by applying `max-width: 480px;`  to the video node.